# Can "that is" mean "I mean"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am reading a text as follow:

Wilbur and I went on a cruise for our honeymoon. It was a shame that Wilbur was so seasick, but we had a good time...when he wasn't feeling sick, that is.

What does "that is" at the end of the text mean? I guess it means "I mean", but I am not sure.

Comment: Related (and ironically asked on the same day as this question): [Meaning of ‘that is’ at the end of a sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157658/that-is-is-so-confusing-please-explain-me-these-sentences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the phrases "that is" and "I mean" interchangeably to express more clearly what you have just said.  These phrases can also be used before the when-clause as follows:

We had a good time, that is, when he wasn't feeling sick.

Answer (score 1):

Yep! It's used to clarify/put the sentence into context, frequently used in a lighthearted tone.